# Highcharts, polar without inner axis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to created Polar Highchart without inner axis (make empty pie inside). There was similar question asked by someone else here with solution like:

```
this.options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: [["Firefox",6],["MSIE",4],["Chrome",7]],
        size: '60%',
        innerSize: '20%',
        showInLegend:true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/

Has anyone achieved same effect in chart like this:

```
this.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        polar: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HCbX8kxvhCDxww3HWiG5?p=preview

Comment: It would be easier to read your question if you included the images directly, rather than as external links. Thanks.

Comment: I do not if or how I can edit question but here is sample of what I want to do: https://ibb.co/deFHTT. I want to have same space in 2 chart as 1 has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to adjust the size of the second chart you need to set the `pane.size` parameter equal to the `series.size` value of the first chart pie series, just like that:

```
       this.options = {
          chart: {
            type: 'column',
            polar: true
          },
          series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
          }],
          pane: {
            size: '60%'
          }
        };
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.size

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/TZiv6POxjmaemk6cpBJc?p=preview

= = = =

**EDIT**

After getting more specified information (in comment below), the answer has completely changed.
We don't have such a feature implemented in polar chart type.

However, all is not lost, because you can get this effect by adding some custom code.

First, you need to render circle on the center of your chart, using `renderer` object on `chart.load` event:

```
           events: {
              load: function() {
                var chart = this
                var center = [chart.chartWidth / 2, chart.chartHeight / 2]
                // Render custom circle on the center of the chart
                chart.renderer.circle(center[0], center[1], 45)
                    .attr({
                    fill: '#fff',
                    stroke: '#ddd',
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    zIndex: 6 // Set Z iIndex smaller than zIndex of yAxis Labels to avoid overlapping
                  })
                    .add()
              }
           }
```

Then, you need to adjust yAxis a bit, namely set the `Axis.min` equal to some negative value, to make the `0` tick located on the middle of the visible part of plot area.

```
    yAxis: {
        min: -130
    }
```

At the end, you need to hide first `yAxis` label, using `labels.formatter` function:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: -130,
        labels: {
            // Hide first axis label
            formatter: function() {
                return this.isFirst ? '' : this.value 
            }
        }
    }
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/zps287e1/

Comment: I think I might have not explained exactly how I should, see this link https://ibb.co/fsgMNo. I want to move the starting point of poles from the middle.

Comment: This was very usefull. Thank you daniel_s.